# Access data stream as it is received

Tags: android, ios, spotify

I've seen mention with the previous SDK as well as the current SDK that it is possible for Spotify songs to stream to the device at 1.5 times faster than their playback length. I am currently overriding the SPTAudioController and can access the audio frames as they are played back through it. My hope was that by overriding `- (NSInteger)attemptToDeliverAudioFrames:(const void *)audioFrames ofCount:(NSInteger)frameCount streamDescription:(AudioStreamBasicDescription)audioDescription` and returning the same count of frames that are passed in, I would immediately receive the next set of frames. This is not the case however, the frames are only delivered as fast as the song is playing, ie. I receive frames the entire time the song is playing.

How can the current Spotify SDK be used to access the audio data as soon as it is received from Spotify?

Note: although the method above is from the iOS SDK, I am interested in answers for both the Android and iOS versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the answer to this is that you aren't allowed to do so, our licenses only allows you to get the data at ~realtime speed.

Same goes for all our SDK's.